# Difference between _module.less and _extend.less

Tags: magento2, frontend, view, less-css, less

Is there any difference between extending a theme using `_module.less` and `_extend.less`? And what is the best practice when extending a module/theme?

My first thought was it's better to use `_module.less` when styling a new module, and `_extend.less` when extending a module. But Luma uses `_module.less` when extending the blank theme so that theory has gone out the window.

The only difference I can see between them is `_module.less` is imported before the responsive library and `_theme.less` where as `_extend.less` is imported after them.

This is the order they are imported in `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-l.less`

```
//
//  Blank theme desktop styles
//  _____________________________________________

//  These desktop styles are added to mobile

//
//  Global lib + theme styles
//  ---------------------------------------------

@import '_styles.less';
@import (reference) 'source/_extends.less';

//
//  Magento Import instructions
//  ---------------------------------------------

//@magento_import 'source/_module.less'; // Theme modules
//@magento_import 'source/_widgets.less'; // Theme widgets

//
//  Media queries collector
//  ---------------------------------------------

@import 'source/lib/_responsive.less';

@media-target: 'desktop'; // Sets target device for this file
@media-common: false; // Sets not to output common styles

//
//  Global variables override
//  ---------------------------------------------

@import 'source/_theme.less';

//
//  Extend for minor customisation
//  ---------------------------------------------

//@magento_import 'source/_extend.less';
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer is somewhat hidden in the Magento docs:

> Extending a theme using **_extend.less** is the simplest option when you are happy with everything the parent theme has, but want to add more styles.

[Read more here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html#simple_extend)

Use **_module.less** when you want to make major changes in styles for a module and use **_extend.less** for minor adjustments. You'll find more examples on how to override component styles in the link above.

Comment: I've read that but it doesn't really explain why, it sounds like there's no reasoning behind it. I'm trying to figure out if there's any difference. I've been using _extend.less for all my changes as I prefer consistency to using something because 'Magento said so'.

Comment: @BenCrook the "why" in the answer is "So that your theme is capable of receiving styling updates from its parent". When you extend a file, you are changing/adding only what is necessary. Whereas if you override it entirely, you must copy/paste all the original source code (that you want retained) and if the parent theme's styling is ever updated, your theme won't receive updates from overridden files.

Comment: @Meogi I get that but doesn't _module.less extend the file, not override previous styling? There is no mention of _module.less in the dev docs other than " General styles for the module are in the _module.less file" and "If variables are local and used only in a module scope, they should be located in the module file".

Comment: @BenCrook if my reading these past few days serves me right, no. If someone were to add any `.less` file in their theme with the same path as a file in the parent theme/module, that is an override. You could probably verify by creating a blank  _module.less into your theme, and seeing if the original styles apply.

Comment: After a `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`, you can look into `pub/static/frontend/<vendor>/<themeName>/<locale>/css/` and `pub/static/frontend/<vendor>/<themeName>/<locale>/<Module_Name>/css/` and there will be symbolic links for *.less files to either your theme, or the module/parent theme it is coming from.

Comment: That is correct _module.less overrides the parent less file, there is no inheritance or merging.

I realise I could have made that more clear in my original answer :)

Comment: This doesn't seem right to me. If I create an _extends.less file it overrides the _extends.less file in the parent theme, screwing everything up. I need to use _module.less to truly extend the parent theme.

Comment: @MattCosentino I realise this reply comes very late, but I'll leave this here in case someone stumbles upon it:

Please note the difference between _extends.less and _extend.less. 

The _extend.less files can be added to any module context, to extend styles from a parent theme. 

The _extends.less is located in the root of the theme and is used to extend existing utilities (refer to <project>/lib/web/css/docs/source/_utilities.less).

Answer (score 8):

Simple explanation or difference between both:

`_extend.less` is the way to extend/modify parent themes styles for example you're happy with your parent theme **Luma** and just want to change the button styles in your custom theme, all you need to do is create a new file `_buttons_extend.less` under `web/css/source` in your custom theme and adjust styles in there. Register this file by adding it to the `_extend.less` file inside your theme directory.

What if you want to extend styles of a module e.g. checkout module, well you can create an `_extend.less` file inside your themes module folder e.g. `Magento_Checkout/web/css/source/_extend.less` and add/extend module styling in there.

Now if I added `_module.less` file inside my module directory `Magento_Checkout/web/css/source/_module.less` I'm intending to override my parent themes styling for this module in which case I need to copy '`_module.less`' file from my parent theme's module directory and make modification to that file in which case this file will replace parent themes `_module.less` file altogether.

Comment: He's never talking about Luma as a parent.

Answer (score 4):

The `_extends.less` with an S at the end within the Blank Theme, is a file where they created all the classes that can be extended via `LESS` later within the theme, without the need of creating new components or modular structure for style changes. -> For those who don't believe me: [check the file](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/web/css/source/_extends.less).

The `_extend.less` without the S at the end, is for when you are 99% happy with what the parent theme has and you just need to change a couple of things, change some styling and that's it.

About the latter one, my personal opinion, don't use it for your own developing. It creates a big mess later. Keep your structure modular with `_module.less` for every module you want to customize and you will get a better outcome & maintainable project at the end.